# How to plot 3 lists in the same graph using ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

Having 3 following lists:

```
  List1 = {{1, 0.`, 37.752812298486035`}, {2, 0.3141592653589793`, 
 37.752812298486035`}, {3, 0.6283185307179586`, 
 37.752812298486035`}, {4, 0.9424777960769379`, 
 37.752812298486035`}, {5, 1.2566370614359172`, 
 37.752812298486035`}, {6, 1.5707963267948966`, 
 37.752812298486035`}}


  {{1, 0.`, 24.272068948311105`}, {2, 0.03192603494711399`, 
  24.272068948311105`}, {3, 1.3000137050160698`, 
  24.272068948311105`}, {4, 1.5611698441441035`, 
  24.272068948311105`}, {5, 1.342322000923152`, 
  24.272068948311105`}, {6, 1.5707963267948966`, 24.272068948311105`}}

  {{1, 0.`, 21.675955239185086`}, {2, 0.03192603494711399`, 
   21.675955239185086`}, {3, 1.5341456365829127`, 
   21.675955239185086`}, {4, 1.5611698441441035`, 
   21.675955239185086`}, {5, 1.342322000923152`, 
    21.675955239185086`}, {6, 1.5707963267948966`, 21.675955239185086`}}
```

How do I plot them all in 1 graph with different colors?

for the explanation in each inner bracket the first number is ne (electron index), second number is the angle (spin angle) and the third number is the energy. Can anybody please help me plot this and identify the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I plot them all in 1 graph with different colors?

If you must use `ListPlot3D` you can use `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to see the surfaces, otherwise, one (the first list) will not show due to how your data is.

```
ListPlot3D[{list1, list2, list3}, InterpolationOrder -> 0,  
     AxesLabel -> {"electron index", "spin angle", "energy"}, 
     BaseStyle -> 12, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not use  `InterpolationOrder -> 0` or use higher interpolation, the first list does not show up

```
ListPlot3D[{list1, list2, list3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Because it can't make a surface otherwise, due to how you first list data is.

`list1,list2,list3` above are your three lists you show.

There might be a better way to visualize your three list, but you said you wanted to use  `ListPlot3D`

Comment: Thank you so much Nasser, Could you inform me about the other way you know. I'm not insisting on using ListPlot3D. What I 'm interested in showing is how the energy is different for each electron-set with a certain angle structure, each of lists1, 2, and 3 belongs to a certain angle set and each angle set has an energy attributed to it

Comment: Great explanation for( InterpolationOrder -> 0) , I guess that was my main problem.

Comment: The reason I want to try the other methods is that these plots do not show or it's not obvious from them how the angles are changing for each list